# Google Analytics showing other property data in the same account?

Tags: azure, google-analytics, google-analytics-4

Recently I set up a new property in a GA account, however it's pulling data from some of the other properties within that account. I can't seem to figure out why.

It's also linked to a Google Ad account that runs ads for different sites, will that affect the GA report?

The website is an azure app deployment, would any of the settings in azure affect that as well?

Your help is much appreciated.

I've tried to create another new property for a different website and that seems to be working fine.